# New Interfaces in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, customer-community, napili, winter16, winter17

I have read about the

- forceCommunity:themeLayout
- forceCommunity:profileMenuInterface
- forceCommunity:searchInterface

  I have implemented them in one of lightning component. I used forceCommunity:themeLayout interface and able to customize my pages in Napili template, but i didn't find any code on how to use the profileMenuInterface and searchInterface.

Any help on this will be helpful

TIA!!

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged winter17 now - winter16 was a long time ago?

Comment: This interfaces has been started from the Winter 16, so. Will tag both of them

Comment: The "Use a custom search component" option is not in **Community Builder-> Settings -> Theme** anymore with Spring 17. I can still create the component but I don't see where I can select it.

Answer (score 0):

Profile and Search interface represents the header search and profile components.
To use it, you should go to **Community Builder-> Settings -> Theme** and check
* Use a custom search component
* Use a custom user profile component

And select the custom components you already created implementing those interfaces